# Block Scope in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, scope

In the code below I'm trying to set one variable (bestInsp) equal to the latest variable in a collection (Inspections) according to the InspectionKey.

I've used print statements inside the for-loop and found that the loop works correctly. However, when I try to use the bestInsp variable outside the For loop it doesn't retain the value I set. From my research I'm thinking it is a Block Scope problem, and the solution says to initialize variables outside the For-loop (which I've done) but it still doesn't work. Is there something I'm overlooking?

```
Dim res As Result
Dim insp As Hansen.CDR.Building.IInspection
Dim bestInsp As Hansen.CDR.Building.IInspection
Dim oldKey As Integer = 0
Dim bestKey As Integer = 0
AddMaxFee = False

For Each insp In oBldgApp.Inspections
  If insp.InspectionType.Code = "Foundation" Then
    If insp.InspectionResult.Code.Length > 0 Then
      oldKey = insp.InspectionKey
      If oldKey >= bestKey Then
        bestKey = oldKey
        bestInsp = insp
      End If
    End If
  End If
Next

If bestInsp.InspectionResult.Code.ToUpper = "FAILED" Then
  AddMaxFee = True
End If
```

EDIT: I solved the problem by deleting

```
Dim bestInsp As Hansen.CDR.Building.IInspection
```

and re-adding it. I guess my compiler just got confused?

Comment: Since `bestInsp` is declared outside the For loop it will retain whatever value was assigned to it when the loop exits (not a block scope problem).  Is it the `If` statement below that is not giving you the unexpected results?

Comment: When I ran a print statement after the Next (outside the for-loop) right before the final if statement it said that bestInsp was blank (had no value set to it). So in turn the final If statement failed because bestInsp.InspectionResult.Code = Nothing

Comment: Then your checks **within** the For loop are not getting triggered as you expect, leaving the  `bestInsp` set to `Nothing`.  Put some more Debug.Print() statements in there to see what is happening.  You probably have some unexpected data that you didn't anticipate...

Comment: When I added a Print() statement right after "bestInsp = insp" that printed bestInsp.InspectionResult.Code it had a value. Do you think I should try adding a print statement outside the If statements before the for loop ends? EDIT: I placed the print statement in the loop but outside the If statements and it doesn't retain a value.

Comment: You could...with just the code posted I don't see why the problem is occurring.  Sorry!

Comment: The loop appears to be looking for the highest inspection key for an inspection which has a code and assigning this to the best key. Is this what you had in mind? It seems odd that your code does not retain its value outside the loop and the oldKey has been declared outside the For..Next loop, and therefore should have scope both before and after. May I also suggested setting Option Explicit On and Option Strict On to see if that triggers any compiler issues?